# Парсинг параметров url на golang

Tags: golang, rest

пишу веб сервис на **golang** c маршрутизацией от **gorilla**. Столкнулся с проблемой необязательных параметров урла. Задача заключается в том, чтобы принять запрос по пути `/{entity}/{id:}/{location}?params=...` и сделать запрос к db(использую **GORM**). Не могу додуматься как грамотно распарсить эти параметры, ведь от этих параметров будет зависеть конечное обращение к db и каких-то параметров может не бытьm, к слову параметры - ограничения для db. Сразу прошу прощения за глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как один из вариантов, можно эти необязательные параметры сделать ссылочными, если nil, то их нет.

предположим, у вас есть параметр  Limit, который ограничивает вывод. тогда в вашей структуре десериализация будет таким:

```
Limit *Limit `json:"limit,omitempty"`
```

в вашем handler можете проверить наличие параметра, а если нет, то задать дефолтовое значение, либо передать это в метод извлеченя из базы.

предположим у вас есть метод извлечения всех юзеров GetUsers, которые принимает необязательный параметр

```
func GetUsers(limit *int) ([]User, error) {}
    var users []User
    query := db.Model(&users)
    if limit != nil {
     query = query.Limit(limit)
    }

    err := q.Find(&users).Error
    ....
    
}
```

все необзательные параметры можно таким образом передавать в слой работы с базой, но не забудьте проверять их валидность. Можно отказаться от указателя и передавать дефолтное значение, заранее прогнав через ваш валидатор.